# ways to store uuid in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, uuid

I was wondering what will be the easiest and efficient way to store UUID in Android? I want to use UUID in my application for bluetooth transfer. The app will generate uuid when it runs for the first time. So how should I store uuid ? So that app will be able to make use of that uuid for its subsequent executions? Should I use Shared Preferences ? How can I use shared preferences to store uuid?

my line to create uuid is :

```
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666");
```

should I store this string

```
 "a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666"
```

in the preference and whenever I require uuid i should retrieve this string and get the uuid as

```
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(that_retrieved_string);
```

or should i serialize it to a file when the app first creates the UUID ? OR how can i store the uuid object in preference? 
correct me if i have stated/thought something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("key_uuid", YOUR_UUID);
editor.commit();
```

//This stores your UUID

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String that_retrieved_string=sPrefs.getString("key_uuid",null);
```

//gets the uuid

Basiclly you have many storage options. and they all work fine. Other options include database or store in a external file, but in this cast SharedPreference should be good enough.

Comment: i will try this and get back to you if i have an doubts

Comment: no it is not working..... i cannot write editor.putString("key_uuid", YOUR_UUID);   I should use YUOR_UUID.toString() to make it working because editor.putString(); is of type (String, String) and not of (String, UUID) ? how should I do it?

Comment: Because I will get an error when I want to retrieve back the UUID, If I store it as UUIT.toString() I cant get bagk the UUID because casting to UUID is not possible..... so I cannot store it as a string in in the preference.....? what is other way to store it in the preference?

Comment: just one question? my generated UUID is always the same if i generate it using the same string??